# How to make an ascii-gif like this?

Tags: gif, distort, ascii

Can someone explain to me how this gif is done? I already know that it looks like some kind of Ascii, but how can i get some kind of color scheme and this little distortion effect on it? I would also like to know how the flowing text was made.

Thanks

[image: the gif i was talking about]

Comment: You can make gifs using Photoshop or similar raster image editors such as GIMP or Krita.  This question is really too broad. You could look up tutorials for creating ascii text art as a start, then look up tutorials for creating animated gifs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The way I would do it is simply by making a set of flat images that I need. The distortion could simply be a rectangle here and there.
2. To separate the colors you can export the different zones of color in different images to be composited later.
3. Export them to the desired size and use an Image to ASCII converter. There are some online.
4. Then assembling back the image. If the image is a text output you can change the color of the font and composite the colors on any Image Manipulation program.